# cant get my custom exception message from Exception Controller

Tags: rest, spring-boot, exception

Why i recived "Unable to find com.example.Api_Angular.Dao.Person with id 4" instead of "Person with this id does not exist".

```
 @GetMapping("/persons/{id}")
    public Person getPerson(@PathVariable int id)
    {
        Person person = personService.getPersonById(id);
        System.out.println(person);
        if(!(person instanceof Person))
        {
            throw new NoPersonException("Person with this id does not exist");
        }
        return person;
        }
```

**What im getting:**

```
{
"status": 400,
"msg": "Unable to find com.example.Api_Angular.Dao.Person with id 4",
"request": "uri=/myApp/persons/4"
}
```

**What it should be:**

```
{
"status": 400,
"msg": "Person with this id does not exist",
"request": "uri=/myApp/persons/4"
}
```

**My custom exception:**

```
public class NoPersonException extends RuntimeException {
    String msg;

    public String getMsg() {
        return msg;
    }

    public NoPersonException() {
    }

    public NoPersonException(String message) {
        this.msg = message;
    }
}
```

**Error response:**

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ErrorDetails {

    private int status;
    private String msg;
    private String request;

    public ErrorDetails() {
    }
}
```

**Exception controller:**

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class CustomizedResponseEntityExceptionHandler{


    @ExceptionHandler
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorDetails> response(NoPersonException e,WebRequest webRequest)
    {
        ErrorDetails customerErrorResponse=new ErrorDetails(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value(),e.getMessage(),webRequest.getDescription(false));

        return new ResponseEntity<>(customerErrorResponse,HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorDetails> generalresponse(Exception e,WebRequest webRequest)
    {
        ErrorDetails customerErrorResponse=new ErrorDetails(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value(),e.getMessage(),webRequest.getDescription(false));

        return new ResponseEntity<>(customerErrorResponse,HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
```

Is there problem with type of exception which is called?
Have you any solution how to solve this problem?
Im using spring boot 2.2.

Answer (score 0):

It sure looks like you are getting an `EntityNotFoundException` when you call `personService.getPersonById(id)`. You should try wrapping that in a `try/catch` block to learn more.